# How to get the number of unique values in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a JSON object returned to me from an AJAX request. I know how to add up totals of values belonging to a key in an array/object. But how can I do that dynamically? It's probably really simple and I'm just missing the point, I can imagine it involves another array. **The example I am using is to get the total from each country**, I have removed irrelevant information from the example.

```
{
"message": [
      {
        "login_country_name": "Great Britain"
      },
      {
        "login_country_name": "Great Britain"
      },
      {
        "login_country_name": "United States"
      },
      {
        "login_country_name": "Localhost"
      },
      {
        "login_country_name": "Netherlands"
      }
    ]
}
```

Expecting the results to be something similar to:

```
("Great Britain": 2, "United States": 1, "Localhost": 1, "Netherlands": 1)
```

Comment: The total of what? Number of occurence?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. I assume from the context you're trying to get the number of unique values?

Comment: Seems like you have removed relevant information as well ;)

Comment: "add up totals of values belonging to a key" where is relevant information in example JSON

Comment: Sorry for not being clear! I've updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to loop over data and count number for every unique value.

```js
var d = {
  "message": [{
    "login_country_name": "Great Britain"
  }, {
    "login_country_name": "Great Britain"
  }, {
    "login_country_name": "United States"
  }, {
    "login_country_name": "Localhost"
  }, {
    "login_country_name": "Netherlands"
  }]
}
var r = {};

d.message.forEach(function(o){
  r[o.login_country_name] = (r[o.login_country_name] || 0) +1
});

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 4):

Iterate over the array and generate the result. You can use **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method for that.

```js
var data = {
  "message": [{
    "login_country_name": "Great Britain"
  }, {
    "login_country_name": "Great Britain"
  }, {
    "login_country_name": "United States"
  }, {
    "login_country_name": "Localhost"
  }, {
    "login_country_name": "Netherlands"
  }]
};

var res = data.message.reduce(function(obj, v) {
  // update country count , where `(obj[v.login_country_name] || 0)` helps to avoid undefined retrns `0` if undefined
  obj[v.login_country_name] = (obj[v.login_country_name] || 0) + 1;
  // return the updated object
  return obj;
  // set initial value as an object which stores the result
}, {})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an object and the countries as keys.

```js
var object = { "message": [{ "login_country_name": "Great Britain" }, { "login_country_name": "Great Britain" }, { "login_country_name": "United States" }, { "login_country_name": "Localhost" }, { "login_country_name": "Netherlands" }] },
    count = Object.create(null);

object.message.forEach(function (a) {
    count[a.login_country_name] = (count[a.login_country_name] || 0) + 1;
});

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
  "message": [{
    "login_country_name": "Great Britain"
  }, {
    "login_country_name": "Great Britain"
  }, {
    "login_country_name": "United States"
  }, {
    "login_country_name": "Localhost"
  }, {
    "login_country_name": "Netherlands"
  }]
}
var _getObj = obj.message;
var grouped=[];
_getObj.forEach(function(item) {
  if (!this[item["login_country_name"]]) { // if item dont exist then create a new
    this[item["login_country_name"]] = {

        name: item["login_country_name"],
        qty: 0
      };
      grouped.push(this[item["login_country_name"]])
  }
  this[item["login_country_name"]].qty = this[item["login_country_name"]].qty + 1;


}, Object.create(null)) // create an empty object
console.log(grouped)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/u7gdatgj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need?

```js
var message = [
  {
    "login_country_name": "Great Britain"
  },
  {
    "login_country_name": "Great Britain"
  },
  {
    "login_country_name": "United States"
  },
  {
    "login_country_name": "Localhost"
  },
  {
    "login_country_name": "Netherlands"
  },
  {
    "login_country_name": "Great Britain"
  }
];

var newMessage = [];
$.each(message, function(key, value) {
  if (newMessage.length < 1) {
    newMessage.push(value);
    
  } else {
    var dIndex = -1;
    $.each(newMessage, function(idx, val) {
      if (value.login_country_name === val.login_country_name) dIndex = idx;
    });
   
    if (dIndex == -1) {
      value.count = 1;
      newMessage.push(value);
    } else {
      newMessage[dIndex].count = (newMessage[dIndex].count || 1) + 1;
    }      
  }
});

console.log(newMessage);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```